# How to return the main view in another action within same controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, error-handling, view

So I'm struggling to tackle the following problem:

I have a main view called ApiBroker, in this view there are several methods to do something with the input from this view.

For example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddApi(ApiRedirect model)
    {
        var data = model;
        try
        {
            List<ApiRedirect> list = dbProducts.ApiRedirects.ToList();
            int companyID = dbProducts.Companies.Where(x => x.CompanyName == model.Company.CompanyName).FirstOrDefault().CompanyID;
            int mappingID = dbProducts.MappingNames.Where(x => x.Name == model.MappingName.Name).FirstOrDefault().MappingID;
            ApiRedirect api = new ApiRedirect();
            api.ApiName = model.ApiName;
            api.CompanyID = companyID;
            api.ApiURL2 = model.ApiURL2;
            api.MappingID = mappingID;
            api.ResponseType = model.ResponseType;
            dbProducts.ApiRedirects.Add(api);
            dbProducts.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

This view should return the main View(Index) but instead of doing that its trying to return the View "AddApi" which does not exist. Error:

[image]

With the code above, the data gets inserted into my database but its returning me a 500 error.

What I've tried:

I've tried returning my View hard coded like this: **return View("~/Views/ApiBroker/Index.cshtml");** but this gives me an error in my WebGrid.

I've also tried using "Return View("Index")", however this is me the following error in my WebGrid:

[image]

I've also tried **"return View("Index",YourModel);"**, this is giving me the following error:

[image]

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a particular `View` if they belong to the same `Controller` like this:

```
return View("Index");
```

If the `View` belongs to a different `Controller`, then you would simply have to specify the name of the `View` and its folder name and call it like this:

```
return View("../ControllerName/Index");
```

Comment: @NielsStenden It is a `BinderExeception` which means that you would need to send a model to populate your `webgrid`. Do something like: `return View("Index",YourModel);`

Comment: @NielsStenden You need to return the object of the class: `return View("Index",api);` and then in your `View`, you would have something like this: `@model ApiRedirect`. If the binding is correctly done after your `Controller` call, then the `webgrid` should render properly otherwise you have to check at controller level, what data is being populated in your model.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return RedirectToAction("YourAction");
```

or

```
return RedirectToRoute("YourRouteName");
```